# Python ftplib.dir() Function Not Working

Tags: python

I Have this Code... i want to see this directory on my ftp server. In that dir i have 3 files but my code reads only 2. And it throws an error which i handle. Take a look on the code and the output

```
import datetime
import ftplib
import os
errors = 0
default_ftp_name = 'username'
default_ftp_pass = 'pass'
host = 'ftp.example.com'
print('Connecting To ' + host)
try:
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(host)
    print('Successfully connected! ')
except:
    print('[!]Failed To Connect')
    errors += 1
print('Logging with: ' + default_ftp_name)
try:
    ftp.login(default_ftp_name,default_ftp_pass) 
    print('Login Success')
except:
    print('[!]Couldnt log in')
    errors += 1
print('Changing Directory to /Public/ConnectedUsers/')
try:
    ftp.cwd('/Public/ConnectedUsers/')
except:
    print('[!]Directory failed to change')
    errors += 1
try:
    print('Retrieving Files...')
    files = ftp.dir()
    print(files)
except:
    print('[!]Didnt Get The Files')
    errors += 1
    print('[t] Total Errors: ' + str(errors))
    connection = False

if connection is True:
    #Dosomehting
    var = 10
else:
    print('Connection Error')
```

See the output right here.
it shows 2 items but i have 3.
What do i need to change in order to access all files?

Take a look here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQDyv.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ftp.dir` prints the output to stdout, so `files` is currently `None`. You want to replace that call with `ftp.nlst` (or `ftp.retrlines` with a callback handler). See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.nlst).

Comment: files = ftp.nlst() Doesnt Work

Comment: @FrozenBlade what do you mean? Does it return empty lists? Throw an error?

Comment: @FrozenBlade what error? It might be useful to `except` only expected errors; naked except will catch everything from out of memory to ctrl+c

Comment: I solved it! its an ascii issue no worries its ok thanks for Responding +1 :D

Comment: @FrozenBlade +1? You should actually upvote/accept an answer if it helped. If not, no big deal, but say so. Ideally the problem and solution will be clear for future visitors who search for this sort of problem.